# How to use one vendor chunk file (webpack) for multiple react projects

Tags: git, reactjs, webpack, bundle, commonschunkplugin

I have different gits with different react applications. Where every application should use the same vendors chunk file with external packages (React, ReactDOM ...)

#### Projects setup:

```
Project 1 (git)
   /dist/...
   /src/...
   webpack.config.js
Project 2 (git)
   /dist/...
   /src/...
   webpack.config.js
Project N (git)
   ...
```

Every `webpack.config.js` contains this configuration but with different Library name:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
      app: './src/App.ts',
      vendor: ['react', 'react-dom', 'react-redux', 'redux', 'redux-thunk']
  },
  output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
      filename: '<Name>.bundle.js',
      library: "<Name>",
      libraryTarget: "umd"
  },
  module: { /* ... */ },
  plugins: [
      new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
          name: 'vendor',
          filename: 'vendor.bundle.js'
      })
  ]
}
```

#### Problem:

Webpack builds a `vendor.bundle.js` especially for the current library/project, not for global use, is there an option for webpack creating a `vendor.bundle.js` which can be included on a single page where both applications can be loaded based on this file:

#### Example:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script src="/vendor.bundle.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <script src="/app1.bundle.js"></script>
      <script src="/app2.bundle.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [DllPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/dll-plugin/). You would need an additional Webpack configuration file, let's say `webpack.vendor.config.js` with the common dependencies, for example: `'react', 'react-dom', 'react-redux', 'redux', 'redux-thunk'`. This bundle would be completely decoupled from the rest of the projects.

Once you have this working, it will create a `manifest.json` that can be used from your different projects, so no need to use the `webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin` plugin, but the [DllReferencePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/dll-plugin/#dllreferenceplugin) instead.

With this approach, your different project's bundle files will be smaller, which means shorter build and rebuild times.

Comment: There's the problem of managing the dll chunk. How do you keep every project sync on the version of vendor modules(including babel-runtime where polyfills came from), the version of webpack and the verison of babel?

Comment: So all the common dependencies added in webpack.vendor.config.js file can be added as externals in another config files?